# How can find similarity between sentences?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I'm trying to find similarities between both the sentences in a shell script.

Have a two sentences containing duplicate words, for example, the input data in file `my_text.txt`

```
Shell Script.
Linux Shell Script.
```

- The intersection of both sentences: `Shell`  + `Script`
- The union " size "  of both sentences: `3`

The correct output for similarity of sentences  :

```
 0.30000000000000000000
```

The definition of the similarity ** is the intersection of words between the two sentences divided by the size of the union of the two sentences.

The problem: I have tried a lot to found a shell script, but I have not found a solution to this problem.

Comment: does the data file actually contain `1- ` and `2- ` at the beginning of the lines (if not, remove them and show **only** what's in the file)? show us the numbers ('intersection', 'union', 'quotient') for these 2 sentences; what code have you tried so far?

Comment: Split each sentence into a list or set of words. Then intersect and unite these lists/sets. You can do it in bash, but other languages would probably be better (faster to implement and faster to execute).

Comment: I remove them from the file, the definition of the similarity ** is  the intersection of words between the two sentences divided by the size of the union of the two** I want to used bash, I am solved it by used python, but I have tried a lot to found the solution in a bash

Comment: Can you give the expected results for the following pairs of sentences? **1.** `a b b` and `a b`. **2.** `A` and `a`. **3.** `a` and `a.`.

Comment: I mean by the intersection the common words between the two sentences, the union I mean the length of the sentence , the ratio of similarity it can be between ( 1 to zero )

Comment: I understood these coarse requirements. However, some finer details are still unclear (repeated words in one sentence, case-sensivity, non-letter characters). Therefore I asked using examples.

Comment: I should delete the repeated words, convert the the both sentences to small letter and remove stopword such as [ is, a, to, be by the , and, for ]

Comment: I modified the text to make it easier to read because what I mentioned in the following comment is easy to do

Comment: given the current set of input data ... update the question to show the expected output (not everyone is going to scan the comments trying to piece together the whole picture)

Comment: When  you say above `I want to used bash` - if by that you mean just using bash builtins and avoiding the mandatory Unix tools like grep, sed, awk, sort, cut, bc, etc. then that is a very bad idea as manipulating text is not what any shell, including bash, is designed to do. A shell is an environment to manipulate files and processes and synchronize calls to tools, not to manipulate text - the guys who invented shell also invented tools to be called from shell to manipulate text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script should do the trick.
It also ignores duplicated words per sentence, filler words, and non-alphabetical characters as described by you in the comment section.

```
words=$(
  < my_text.txt tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' |
  grep -Eon '\b[a-z]*\b' |
  grep -Fwvf <(printf %s\\n is a to be by the and for) |
  sort -u | cut -d: -f2 | sort
)
union=$(uniq <<< "$words" | wc -l)
intersection=$(uniq -d <<< "$words" | wc -l)
echo "similarity is $(bc -l <<< "$intersection/$union")"
```

The output for your example input is `.30000000000000000000` (= 0.3).

Comment: How to make a comparison between the first sentence of the second sentence and the first sentence with the third sentence and so on, and calculate the similarity ؟

Comment: You can replace `< my_text.txt ...` by `sed -n '1p;3p' | ...` to compute the similarity between line `1` and `3`. Replace `3` by a loop variable to compute multiple similarites. If you want all pairs of similarities (e.g. 1:2, 1:3, 1:4, …, 2:3, 2:4, …, 3:4, ...) use two nested loops. However, if this is to slow, open a followup question. There are more efficient approaches for this task.

Comment: I asked the question again. I hope you will help me and thank you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65373832/how-to-make-a-comparison-between-sentences-and-calculate-the-similarity

Comment: @ Ed Morton Yes, your method is excellent, but I want to use the bash, is there a possibility to help me using the bash and the command line?

Comment: Calling awk from bash is no different than calling grep, uniq, sort, or cut from bash, they're all mandatory tools used in all Unix boxes and none of them are bash builtins.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do (using GNU awk for FPAT and arrays of arrays)?

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split("is a to be by the and for",tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        stopwords[tmp[i]]
    }
    FPAT="[[:alnum:]_]+"
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        word = tolower($i)
        if ( !(word in stopwords) ) {
            words[NR][word]
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (word in words[1]) {
        if (word in words[2]) {
            numCommon++
        }
    }
    totWords = length(words[1]) + length(words[2]) - numCommon
    print (totWords ? numCommon / totWords : 0)
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
0.666667
```