# How to make a comparison between sentences and calculate the similarity?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line

How to make a comparison between the first sentence of the second sentence and the first sentence with the third sentence and so on, and calculate the similarity using `shell script` or `bash`

I have a sentences containing duplicate words, for example, the input data in file `my_text.txt`
and should ignore duplicated words per sentence, filler words, and non-alphabetical characters.

> Shell Script
> Linux Shell Script
> Shell or bash are fun

I  used this shell script to find similarity

```
  words=$(
  < my_text.txt tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' |
  grep -Eon '\b[a-z]*\b' |
  grep -Fwvf <(printf %s\\n is a to be by the and for) |
  sort -u | cut -d: -f2 | sort
  )
  union=$(uniq <<< "$words" | wc -l)
  intersection=$(uniq -d <<< "$words" | wc -l)
  echo "similarity is $(bc -l <<< "$intersection/$union")"
```

The script Above calculates similarity for all sentences one time, but I want to find want all pairs of similarities (e.g. 1:2, 1:3, 1:4, …, 2:3, 2:4, …, 3:4, ...)

I want to find similarity like this 2 example:

- **for the first and second sentences:**
- The intersection of both sentences: `Shell + Script`
- The union " size " of both sentences: `3`
- **The similarity** : `0.66666666`

### --

- **for the first and third sentences** :
- The intersection of both sentences: `Shell`
- The union " size " of both sentences: `4`
- **The similarity** : `0.25`

can somebody help?

Comment: Could you please explain _The union " size " of both sentences_ and _The similarity_

Comment: `The similarity` calculated as the size of the intersection of words between the two sentences divided by the size of the union of the two sentences:
`=(1∩2)(1∪2)`
A value “0” means the two sentences are completely dissimilar, “1” that they are identical, and values between 0 and 1 representing a degree of similarity.

Comment: Assuming you want to ignore the same set of words you listed in your previous question and as shown in your example code, the size of the union of the words in your second example is 6 (`shell, script, or, bash, are, fun`), not 4, so the expected output should be `0.166667`, not `0.25`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a small tweak to my answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65365496/1745001), still using GNU awk for FPAT and arrays of arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split("is a to be by the and for",tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        stopwords[tmp[i]]
    }
    FPAT="[[:alnum:]_]+"
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        word = tolower($i)
        if ( !(word in stopwords) ) {
            words[NR>1?2:1][word]
        }
    }
}
NR > 1 {
    numCommon = 0
    for (word in words[1]) {
        if (word in words[2]) {
            numCommon++
        }
    }
    totWords = length(words[1]) + length(words[2]) - numCommon
    print (totWords ? numCommon / totWords : 0)
    delete words[2]
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
0.666667
0.166667
```