# Find the similarity between each pair of sentences in a text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a text file which contains some sentences. and I need to compute the similarity between each pair of sentences   (e.g. 1:2, 1:3, 1:4, …, 2:3, 2:4, …, 3:4, ...) ,
here is how similarity is computed :
for example similarity between the first and the second sentence is(  the intersection between them / the union of them  )
i have tried this code

```
words=$(
  < file.txt tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' |
  grep -Eon '\b[a-z]*\b' |
  grep -Fwvf <(printf %s\\n is a to be by the and for) |
  sort -u | cut -d: -f2 | sort
)
union=$(uniq <<< "$words" | wc -l)
intersection=$(uniq -d <<< "$words" | wc -l)
echo "similarity is $(bc -l <<< "$intersection/$union")"
```

but it computes the similarity between all the sentences not each pair ,
how can i fix that?

**example of the text file : **

**Linux is fun**

**bash and Linux**

**hello Linux**

(note that each line contains one sentence )

similarity between line 1 and line 2 = 1/5

The intersection of both sentences: Linux

Comment: The similarity in the example is based on what? Linux? Shouldn't it be 1 and 3 in that case?

Comment: The intersection is " Linux" and the union is " Linux is fun bash and linux " but the word "linux "here is repeated twice so i had to omit it once

Comment: Is each sentence on one line?

Comment: Looks very similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65384114/how-to-make-instead-loop-to-find-similarity-between-pairs-sentences-in-shell-scr

Comment: yeah each line contains one sentence @RamanSailopal

Comment: @KamilCuk page not found :((

Comment: `output : similarity between line 1 and line 2 = 1/5` What should the output be for the input you provided? Note that your code outputs `0.20000` _not_ `"1/5"`. `page not found` Och, it's a deleted question by https://stackoverflow.com/users/14383499/a99j @a99j user , probably you need more reputation on this site to see deleted answers. It has a very, very similar question with almost same code, except he used `sed` in place of `tr`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65373832/how-to-make-a-comparison-between-sentences-and-calculate-the-similarity

Answer (score 1):

Using the example file and assuming each sentence finishes with a full stop:

```
Linux is fun

bash and Linux

hello linux.

Hell this is a

test. This test is a

test.
```

Using awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { 
              RS="." # Set the record separator to a full stop
           } 
           { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { # Loop through each word in the sentence
                 if (map[$i]) { 
                     print map[$i]"/"i-1 # If the word exists in an array map, print the content of the array (the position) followed by / and the position of this entry minus 1.
                 } 
                 map[$i]=i  # Add to the map array with the index the word and the value the position in the sentence
             } 
             delete map # Delete the array
            }' file
```

One liner:

```
 awk 'BEGIN { RS="." } { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if (map[$i]) { print map[$i]"/"i-1 } map[$i]=i  } delete map }' file
```

Output:

```
1/5
2/4
```